# Date problem when importing CSV files from Excel to Plot.ly

Tags: plotly

I am graphing csv files generated in excel in Plot.ly. It has dates starting in 1/31/1900. Plot.ly appears to only use 2 digits for the year and so confuses 1900 and 2000... Any advice on how to generate the csv file in Excel so that it imports the date properly into Plot.ly? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example csv that works for a Plotly time series plot:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv

https://community.plot.ly/t/ploting-time-series-data/5265

Note the date format used is : 2015-02-17

Comment: The date in the file is formatted yyyy-MM-dd, however after I import it Plot.ly only shows the date as 2 digits for the year.